# GPS location provider gives me null location in Android

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager, locationlistener

I try to find location using `GPS_Provider` in android. when try to get location using `Network_Provider` than it give me location and call callback function properly, but when I tried to get location using `GPS_Provider` than it give me location **null** & also not calling callback function `onLocationChanged` of `LocationListener`.

**My code is:**

```
 LocationManager lm;
    boolean isNetwork = false;
    Location location;
    LocationListener locationListener;
    LocationListener loc;
    MyLocation myLocation;
    Location location1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        try {
            myLocation = new MyLocation();

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                Log.e("Location", "Permission Not Given");
                return;
            }
            Log.e("Location", "Permission is Given");
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, myLocation);
            location1=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
```

**MyLocation.class**

```
public class MyLocation implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if(location!=null)
        {

            String lat,Longi;
            lat=String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
            Longi=String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());

            Log.e("Latitude: " , lat);
            Log.e("Longitude: " , Longi);

        }
        else
            Log.e("Location is null", "Location not Found");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.e("Latitude: " ,""+ provider+ " Status: "+status);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.e("Latitude: " , provider);
    }
}
```

It give me logcat error as follow:

```
02-04 00:50:52.280 14480-14480/com.arc.locationusingnetwork E/Location: Permission is Given
02-04 00:50:52.360 14480-14480/com.arc.locationusingnetwork E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 46
02-04 00:50:52.370 14480-14480/com.arc.locationusingnetwork E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 49
02-04 00:50:52.370 14480-14480/com.arc.locationusingnetwork E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
02-04 00:50:52.380 14480-14480/com.arc.locationusingnetwork E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
02-04 00:50:52.380 14480-14480/com.arc.locationusingnetwork E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
02-04 00:50:52.390 14480-14480/com.arc.locationusingnetwork E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 52
```

Comment: @VPS: try using Google Fused Location api for Location Updates. * GPS dosen't works under roof.

Comment: `location1=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);` are you talking about this being null?

Comment: location1=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); gives null & callback function also not calling @MuhammadBabar

Comment: this is normal, if you had read the docs it clearly states `getLastKnowLocation()` will return **null** if no last know location exists on the device!

Comment: `onLocationChange()` will only be called when device is able to connect to satellite gps and get a location fix. Also do note Gps doesn't work indoors, so you would need a clear sky to get gps location!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old LocationListener class is probably deprecated. You should use [FusedLocationApi](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) by Android to fetch current location or receive location updates via FusedLocationAPI's LocationListener.

It's a good tutorial for using FusedLocationApi : [Android Location API](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/)

Comment: May be, but the official Android guide suggests to use FusedLocationApi for location related operations. I too experienced problems (receiving null values) from the old LocationListener. While the problem was solved after using the new API.

Comment: FusedLocationApi is more accurate, drains more battery. LocationListener is less accurate, and it jumps(like it will show you at one point, then the next second you are in another point), drains less battery therefore LocationListener is useful if you need a rough estimate location. I had no problems using LocationListener.

Comment: @j4rey89 I'm afraid dear but your assumptions are wrong. According to Google , FusedLocationApi is more efficient , accurate and uses LESS power than any other old API. For details watch Google I/O video session on Location : [Google I/O 2013 - Beyond the Blue Dot: New Features in Android Location](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bte_GHuxUGc)

Comment: @VPS You can check the links I have mentioned in my answer. They contain a full guide to using the API.

Comment: @Tafveez Mehdi If you set the priority to low then yes.......another point is that you need Google Api.......and that increases your apk size.

Comment: I think it's time for you to stop making assumptions :) If Google has suggested something , it means it's better to use. And would apk size increase by 500KB using playservices? Whoa! Does that even matter?!

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your device to call `onLocationChanged` of `LocationListener` as
`LocationListener` is Used for receiving notifications from the `LocationManager` when the location has changed. These methods are called if the `LocationListener` has been registered with the location manager service using the `LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(String, long, float, LocationListener)` method.

Now there is no guarantee that `getLastKnownLocation` always return `Location` as it returns last location but if app is installed freshly or user did clear data then gps last known location returns `null` so to handle this you should move your device so that `onLocationChanged` is called ( I recommend to move in open so that device connect to gps fast).

**OR**

You can use `FusedLocationProviderApi` as it is the **latest API** and the best among the available possibilities to get location in Android.
[google docs : Getting the Last Known Location](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#last-known)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your GNSS/GPS is Enabled?

```
boolean gpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```